# What are the empty home and net drives?

Tags: macos, finder, network, mount

I have two drives on my Mac which are always empty (I've enabled show hidden files in the Finder):

[image]

What are these drives for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're *always* seeing them -- I don't, even with hidden files enabled -- but they're the root directories commonly used by the automounter when you connect your Mac to an NFS network (which generally means a Unix/Linux network). Users' home directories are usually mounted under /home, and other shared filesystems under /net.