# What are the home and net folders I see within finder?

Tags: macos, finder

While a similar question was raised [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9341/what-are-the-empty-home-and-net-drives), it doesn't seem to be a solid answer but more of a theory. In addition my case is a bit different as you will see below.

[image: MacBook Air view]

You will note that I have two *home* drives, one being a mount to a share on my NAS and the other in question being the one within localhost.

What value do the home and net drives within localhost serve other than being part of default *nix folder structure? Is this anything more than a local representation that exists by *nix default? Is it safe to eject these drives or is the OS using them in some fashion which may not be readily apparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole "root" directory you picture, and finder shows actually does not exist at all. It's kind of a "meta" directory. The unix root directory (e.g. `/`) points to the folder OS X calls "Macintosh HD". **Everything** is a sub-directory of that, even other drives.

Basically, when you connect a external drive, insert a CD, mount a `DMG`, or map a network drive, the resources contained within the new drive are actually made available (called "mounting") as a subdirectory of `/Volumes/[Drive name here]`.
Finder (and *finder only*) has a facility that shows a fake-directory that contains all the mounted drives.

In other words, the reason you can have two `home` directories is because they're not actually in the same folder. One is actually located at `/Volumes/home` and the other is `/home`.

Anyways...

---

The `home` and `net` directories actually exist as folders on your main drive. If you open the root directory of your drive (IN your picture, its labeled "Macintosh HD"), you'll see where they are actually located.

The `home` directory seems to be related to enterprise environments, where various network drives can be defined using a directory service. I believe that, in such a situation, the automounted drives appear in `/home/[Network drive name]`, rather then the OS X traditional `/Volumes/[Drive name]`. In any event, it's part of the `autofs` underpinnings of OS X. [More here](http://lowendmac.com/ed/winston/09kw/intro-to-autofs.html).

The `/net` directory also seems to be related to the automounter. There is a thread about it on the apple support forums [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1560715?start=0&tstart=0).

> /net is built into the automounter in OS X and uses the special map
>   -hosts. This built in map will consist of the exports from the named server, when that server is accessed via the /net path. For example,
>   if I have an NFS server at the IP address 192.168.1.10 and it exports
>   a directory /exports, then if I do this from my Mac:
>
> prompt$ cd /net/192.168.1.10/exports
>
> the Mac automounter will contact the server, mount the export, and put
>   me in that directory. All without me having to issue any "mount"
>   command.

As such, it may be possible to use the `/net` directory as a shortcut to access network drives, assuming you're working from the command line. It doesn't seem to work for SMB (i.e. windows) shares (at least for me), though.

Incidentally, if you want to look at what's mounted where, all you have to do is open a command-prompt, and type `mount`. It will return a list of all the drives your computer has, and where they are mounted.

Comment: It sounds like they are part of the underpinnings of OS X and have no _real_ benefit other than being just that, underpinnings. While they _could_ be used for certain scenarios it doesn't sound conducive or the norm in an OS X environment. Thanks for the great write up!