# Empty /home directory, and I can't delete it?

Tags: root

I have got a `/home` directory with no content. When trying to delete it by `sudo rm -rf /home`, OS X warns "rm: /home: Resource busy" and refuses to do it.   Tried reboot. `lsof` returns nothing related.

Does anyone know why could this happen, and, especially, how can I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

it is set up by the system for scenarios with network home directories, which are mounted at /home. we use network homes for a number of our Mac desktops, and, in our case, if a user has a home directory specified in Active Directory, and the AD plugin is set to use it, it will mount under /home.

my guess would be that the system doesn't allow it to be deleted because of that (at minimum).

Answer (score 1):

/home and /net are both meta directories related to `autofs` & `/etc/auto_master` and part of the standard installation.

Please read more here: [What are the home and net folders I see within finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72762/what-are-the-home-and-net-folders-i-see-within-finder)

Comment: thanks. I don't remember seeing these before...